# Connect to a remote machine with c socket

Tags: c, sockets, serversocket

I have this problem with c Socket: the connection in localhost work but if I have a  client in a different machine code doesn't work.

SERVER:

```
int my_socket;

my_socket = socket(PF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,IPPROTO_TCP);

if(my_socket <0) {
    errorhandler("socket creation failed.\n");
    clearwinsock();
    return -1;
}
struct sockaddr_in sad;
memset(&sad, 0, sizeof(sad));
sad.sin_family = AF_INET;
sad.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
sad.sin_port = htons( port ); //(port=8080)
```

CLIENT:

```
int c_socket;
c_socket = socket(PF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,IPPROTO_TCP);
if(c_socket<0) {
    errorhandler("socket creation failed.\n");
    closesocket(c_socket);
    clearwinsock();
    return -1;
}

struct sockaddr_in sad;  
memset(&sad, 0, sizeof(sad));
sad.sin_family = AF_INET;
sad.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("172.26.188.19");
sad.sin_port = htons(PROTOPORT); 
if (connect(c_socket, (struct sockaddr *)&sad, sizeof(sad))< 0) {
    errorhandler( "Failed to connect.\n" );
    closesocket(c_socket);
    clearwinsock();
    return -1;
}
```

The problem is that the connect() of client return <0.

Comment: When you get an error, check `errno` for what went wrong. You can use e.g. `strerror` to get a printable string of the error.

Comment: As for possible reasons, do the server actually `listen` on the socket? Does it `accept` new connections?

Comment: Can you post some [MCVE], at least, what are ports and how does the server listen for client...

Comment: This is not the complete code,but the same code that work in localhost doesn't work in remote beacause the connect() in client return<0. Server accepts correctly the connection of client in localhost but in remote no.

Comment: Problem with your firewall that doesn't let the client's communication through?

Comment: Maybe I don;t understand, but the server gets an IP address of `inet_addr("127.0.0.1")` and the client tries to connect to `inet_addr("172.26.188.19")`?

Comment: Your server must also do `bind`, `listen`, `accept` after `socket` call.

Answer (score 1):

[Assuming your server code were complete (and not just the part you show us)]

The server binds to the loopback interface only. This is not reachable from *outside* the server.

To have a server listen on any of its interfaces bind it to `INADDR_ANY` by replacing

```
  sad.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
```

with

```
  sad.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
```

Comment: @SanteAltamura: You are welcome. Still, at SO we say "*Thank you!*" by up-voting, and we say "*It works!*" by accepting the related answer.